# Computer needs a restart if internet connection restarts/disconnect and reconnect in Linux mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint, network-interface, networkmanager, internet

I am working on a `Linux mint` machine in my office. There are two internet connections. We often switch the connection due to the error in one connection. But once the switching is done, I need to restart my machine to reconnect it to the internet.

**My distribution is:** Linux Mint 4.4.0-108-generic

I tried to disable and enable the connection, and run the commands

> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
>
> sudo service networking restart

But one of them doesn't seems working. I still need to restart the machine.

But I couldn't find the issue with others. Only me using `mint`. Others are using `ubuntu`.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Does it work if you do instead `sudo service networking stop` and `sudo service networking start`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I never tried that sequence. But I tried the same from the GUI. Hope both are same. But it still didn't make any change.

Comment: Hoping is not enough. Try it then; I do remember vaguely a bug/issue of this working when `restart` does not work.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, Thanks for the info. Let me check on the next time

Comment: Also, you can post the output of ifconfig before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command to restart the network manager.
**sudo service network-manager restart**

This worked for me.Hope it works for you too.